# Getting value of an attribute in XML of a duplicated element name

Tags: xml, xslt

How would I grab say value3 in XSL if the element `parameter` (nested in `parameters`) is repeated many times?

```
<parameters>
    <parameter name="name1" value="value1"/>
    <parameter name="name2" value="value2"/>
    <parameter name="name3" value="value3"/>
    <parameter name="name4" value="value4"/>
</parameters>
```

If the `parameter` was unique I could just do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="parameters/parameter/@value" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using an index.
For example, to reference the third `parameter` use

```
<xsl:value-of select="parameters/parameter[3]/@value" />
```

Or to reference it by attribute value use

```
<xsl:value-of select="parameters/parameter[@name='name3']/@value" />
```

Comment: What would happen if I specified a `@name` that didn't exist?

Comment: @Sam: Then the predicate would return `FALSE` and the nodeset would be empty. So the whole expression would be empty.